Solve $2Q\mathbf{x}+2c(\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}-b)\cdot\mathbf{a}+2c(\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{x}-1)\cdot\mathbf{1}=\mathbf{0}$

Let $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be positive definite,
$\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be linearly independent of
$\mathbf{1}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $b$ be a constant. Solve the
problem by penalty method: $$\min\mathbf{x}^TQ\mathbf{x}$$ subject to
$$\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}=b,\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{x}=1$$

My answer:
Penalty function $p(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}^TQ\mathbf{x}+c(\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}-b)^2+c(\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{x}-1)^2\implies\nabla p=2Q\mathbf{x}+2c(\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}-b)\cdot\mathbf{a}+2c(\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{x}-1)\cdot\mathbf{1}=\mathbf{0}$
My struggle is mainly about linear algebra technique, that is, to solve for $\mathbf{x}$ is "$\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}-b$" and "$\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{x}-1$". Can anyone suggest any way to solve for $\mathbf{x}$?
Thanks a lot.

can you please clarify what is denoted by $\bf{1}$?

it is $(1,\ldots,1)^T\in\mathbb{R}^n$

Let $   A =\begin{bmatrix} 
a^T   \\
1^T
\end{bmatrix}$.
If  $  \begin{bmatrix} 
b  \\
1
\end{bmatrix} \in range(A)$,
$x = d + v$, where $Ad=[b,1]^T, v\in null(A)$.
Otherwise, no solution, problem is infeasible.

The problem should have solution. Plus can you please explain more about your solutions? I still don't understand. Thanks!

Just solve the linear system. General solution = a special one + null space
